How can I do a join on the same table?
I came to a project where all kind of "characters" are in users table (for example, stores and sellers).
well, in the table exists (id, name, store) and others. In the database exists a "contract" table, and they want a sells report, where they do this sql consult in laravel
$ventasQuery = Contract::select('contracts.*', 'users.name', 'users.store');

 $ventas = $ventasQuery
     ->join('users', 'contracts.vendedor', '=', 'users.id')
     ->orderBy('contracts.id', 'DESC')
     ->get();

with the last code I can call the store.id, but I need to add other join where user.store (I mean, the seller) = user.id (I mean, the store).
by the way, users.store is null when the user is a store, and there is other kind of user called admin, who have more than 1 store in users.store, and I need to call the admin also
then, The current code extract contracts when contract.seller = user.id
and I need to extract users.name when user.store (The seller) = user.id (the store)
and the same with admin. call user.name (the admin) when user.store (the admin) = user.id (the store)

$ventasQuery = Contract::select('contracts.*', 'sellers.name AS seller_name', 'admins.name AS admin_name')
    ->join('users AS sellers', 'contracts.vendedor', '=', 'sellers.id') // Join to get seller's details
    ->leftJoin('users AS admins', function ($join) {
        $join->on('sellers.store', '=', 'admins.id') // Join to get admin's details if seller is not admin themselves
             ->where('admins.type', '=', 'admin'); // Assuming there's a type field to identify admin users
    })
    ->orderBy('contracts.id', 'DESC')
    ->get();

Adjust 'admins.type' to match your actual column name that distinguishes admin users from others.
Ensure your users table structure matches the assumptions (like having a type field to distinguish admins).
This query assumes that if users.store is NULL, the user is a store; otherwise, they are a regular seller associated with that store.
Adjust the conditions (where clause in the leftJoin) based on your actual database structure and business logic.
